# Mulitline RegEx

Tags: php, regex

Consider following text:

```
$content=<<<EOT
    {
        "translatorID": "f4a5876a-3e53-40e2-9032-d99a30d7a6fc",
        "label": "ACL",
        "creator": "Nathan Schneider",
        "target": "^https?://(www[.])?aclweb\\.org/anthology-new/[^#]+",
        "minVersion": "1.0.7",
        "maxVersion": "",
        "priority": 100,
        "browserSupport": "gcs",
        "inRepository": true,
        "translatorType": 4,
        "lastUpdated": "2012-01-01 01:42:16"
    }

    // based on ACM translator
    function detectWeb(doc, url) {
      var namespace = doc.documentElement.namespaceURI;
        var nsResolver = namespace ? function(prefix) {
            if (prefix == 'x') return prefix; else return null;
        } : namespace;

        var bibXpath = "//a[./text() = 'bib']"
        if(doc.evaluate(bibXpath, doc, nsResolver, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext()) {
          return "multiple"
        }
      //commenting out single stuff
      // if (url.indexOf("/anthology-new/J/")>-1)
      //  return "journalArticle";
      // else
      //  return "conferencePaper";
    }
EOT;
```

I want select text between `{` and `}` in the beginning of text. I test following but it did not yield desired text.

```
preg_match('~\{(.*)\}~m',$content,$meta);
var_dump( $meta);
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What is your concrete problem? I mean how can you say this is "wrong"? --- You might be looking for the `s` (PCRE_DOTALL) modifier: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: It is json right? Why don't simply `json_decode()` the data and loop over to display it? I'd rather go for it even it looks useless, using regex for such task won't probably cover all edge cases..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in multiline mode, `.` does not match a newline. You can make it match a newline by using the [`s` (PCRE_DOTALL) modifier](http://php.net/manual/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

```
preg_match('~\{(.*)\}~sm',$content,$meta);
                      ^
```

However your case also requires to make the match non-greedy otherwise this will pick from the source-code below as well:

```
preg_match('~\{(.*?)\}~sm',$content,$meta);
                  ^
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XJ3IGq)

Comment: @Reza: Try the *`Dot matches all`* checkbox. It says as well: *(s; via XRegExp)* - You see the **s** ? ;) - The modifiers are often similar across languages and regex engines.

Answer (score 1):

Cheat sheet http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11su/cheat-sheets/php-regex-cheat-sheet.pdf says:

```
 Base Character Classes
 .  (Period) – Any character except newline
```

But it also says

```
Pattern Modifiers
s   Dotall - . class includes newline
```

Comment: That's why they invented the i modifier.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you are after:

```
preg_match('/\{(.*?)\}/s', $string, $result);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

`preg_match('~\{(.*)\}~m',$content,$meta,PCRE_MULTILINE);`

Adittional documention
http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php